# SQL Query to Entity Framework (ExecuteStoreQuery)

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework

I have a SQL query that works fine and returns proper results

```
DECLARE @memberId DECIMAL 

SET @memberId=100 

SELECT S.ID, 
       S.STATUSDATE, 
       S.STATUSTEXT, 
       P.FIRSTNAME, 
       P.LASTNAME, 
       P.PHOTO 
FROM   MEMBERSTATUS S 
       JOIN PROFILE P 
         ON S.SENDERID = P.MEMBERID 
WHERE  S.SENDERID IN (SELECT F.MEMBERID AS ID 
                      FROM   MEMBER_FRIENDREQUEST F 
                      WHERE  ( F.FRIENDID = @memberId ) 
                             AND F.STATUS = 2 
                      UNION 
                      SELECT F.FRIENDID AS ID 
                      FROM   MEMBER_FRIENDREQUEST F 
                      WHERE  ( F.MEMBERID = @memberId ) 
                             AND F.STATUS = 2 
                      UNION 
                      SELECT @memberId)
```

But when I try to use it in ASP.NET it never returns any result

```
     using (var db = new ExerciseProgramManagerEntities())
            {
                var pMmemberId = new SqlParameter("@memberId", senderId);                                    

                var result  = db.ExecuteStoreQuery<DynamicObject>("select s.Id, s.StatusDate, s.StatusText, p.FirstName, p.LastName, p.Photo "+
 "from MemberStatus s join Profile p on s.SenderId = p.MemberID " +
 "where s.SenderId IN "+
 "("+
"select f.MemberID as id from Member_FriendRequest f where (f.FriendID = @memberId ) and f.Status=2 "+
"union "+
"select f.FriendID as id from Member_FriendRequest f where (f.MemberID=@memberId) and f.Status=2 " +
"union "+
"select @memberId)", pMmemberId);
```

What's wrong in my query?

Comment: No results at all or just empty `DynamicObject`s?

Comment: Set up sql profiler and filter by database and login not to have to many records and check whether query is right and has right parameters.

Comment: Put a break before the `var result =` statement & examine the parameter's datatype.  It's not created as a particular datatype, so that may be what's going on - it's trying to perform a string comparison or something, maybe?